# Was ist die Herkunft von „zumute“?

Tags: etymology, meaning

Was ist die Herkunft von „zumute“ („zu Mute“)? Wie hat sich der Bedeutungsumfang von „Mut“ verändert, und wie haben sich verwandte Wörter in anderen germanischen Sprachen entwickelt?

Comment: Vielleicht ein bisschen interessant: https://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/mut-meaning/

Comment: @Emanuel Könnte man fast umschreiben, und eine Antwort draus machen ;)

Comment: Meinst Du "zumute" wie in "mir ist so traurig zumute" oder "zumute" wie in "was ich mir auf meine alten Tage noch zumute"? Ich vermute ersteres, sonst hättest Du wohl nach dem Infinitiv (zumuten) gefragt.

Comment: @userunknown, Danke, in der Tat ersteres. Ich habe jetzt die alternative Schreibweise hinzugefügt, vielleicht wird es dadurch klarer.

Comment: Es handelt sich um eine typische Bedeutungsverengung. "Mut" war einmal ganz allgemein jede art von Geisteshaltung (z.B. "guten Mutes sein" vs. andere Gemütszustände). Heute bezeichnet es nur noch die Entschlossenheit angesichts von Gefahr (oder wie man den heutigen Mut sonst definieren will).

Comment: @KilianFoth, das ist genau das, worüber ich gerne mehr wüsste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Wort „Mut“ kommt aus den indogermanischen und bedeutet ursprünglich soviel wie:
"sich mühen, starken Willens sein, heftig nach etwas streben"

Im althochdeutschem steht "muot" für "Sinn, Seele, Geist, Gemüt, Kraft des Denkens, Empfindens, Wollens"

Durch diese Definition leiteten sich eben auch verschiedene Redewendungen wie zum Beispiel:

"Wieviel kann ich ihm zumuten?" was als "Wie sehr wird er sich mühen?" oder "Wie heftig wird er danach streben?", interpretiert werden kann.

Ebenso wie  "Das ist nicht zumutbar!", was soviel bedeutet wie "Das kann man nicht verlangen!"